# NDSolve equation gives empty plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
ClearAll[n, c, w1, w2, x, y, g, p1, p2, p3, p4, Eq1, Eq2, sol]

n = 1;

w1 = -(1/3) - 2*(Sqrt[g[x]]*Sqrt[1 - g[x]/y[x]])/3;

w2 = (0.2)*(1 + y[x])^n/(g[x])^(n - 1)*(1 - g[x] + y[x]);

Eq1 = g'[x] == -3*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + 
    y[x]*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1);

Eq2 = y'[x] == -3*y[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + 
    y[x]*(1 + y[x])*(1 + 3*w1);

sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, g[0] == 0.72, y[0] == 0.08}, {g, y}, {x, -10,
     10}, AccuracyGoal -> 2];

p1 = Plot[{Evaluate[{g[x],y[x]} /. sol]}, {x, -10, 10}];
```

**when I try to solve equations the graphs are empty, how can I solve that?**

Comment: Remove `MaxSteps -> 500`

Comment: ok. why my graphs are empty, it is not plotting

Comment: At `x==0`, `g'[x]` and `y'[x]` are complex-valued (`{Eq1, Eq2} /. {g[x] -> 0.72, y[x] -> 0.08}` gives `{Derivative[1][g][x] == 0.319666 + 0.96768 I, 
 Derivative[1][y][x] == 0.0355185 - 0.27648 I}`).  Is that what you expect? I notice you changed the definition of `w1` in your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Real Part

```
ClearAll[n, w1, w2, p1, sol]

n = 1;

w1[x_] := Re[-(1/3) - 2*(Sqrt[g[x]]*Sqrt[1 - g[x]/y[x]])/3];

w2[x_] := Re[(1/5)*(1 + y[x])^n/(g[x])^(n - 1)*(1 - g[x] + y[x])];

sol = NDSolve[{
    g'[x] == -3*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1[x] - w2[x]) + y[x]*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1[x]),
    y'[x] == -3*y[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1[x] - w2[x]) + y[x]*(1 + y[x])*(1 + 3*w1[x]),
    g[0] == 0.72, y[0] == 0.08},
   {g, y}, {x, -10, 10}];

p1 = Plot[{Evaluate[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]

p2 = Plot[{Evaluate[w1[x] /. sol], Evaluate[w2[x] /. sol]}, {x, -10, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotRange -> Full, Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

[image]

Imaginary Part

```
w1[x_] := Im[-(1/3) - 2*(Sqrt[g[x]]*Sqrt[1 - g[x]/y[x]])/3];

w2[x_] := Im[(1/5)*(1 + y[x])^n/(g[x])^(n - 1)*(1 - g[x] + y[x])];
```